# Can RSS readers follow redirects if the url of the feed changes?

Tags: redirect, rss

We are migrating to a Sharepoint solution and our urls are changing slightly.

Are most RSS readers able to follow redirect links without breaking the feed and making an update manually?

Most of the documentation I'm reading says that this will work for major RSS readers.

I have read in some places that a lot of RSS readers will treat a 301 as a temporary redirect and not update its stored url.  Any truth to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using a 301 redirect, I would say yes, since any reader worth its salt is built on a compliant HTTP library which will honor the 301 status code and follow the redirect.

Of course, it's not *that* hard to test with the reader of your choice.

Comment: I don't have a specific reader that I must support and can test with that one, just all the major ones without installing them all and testing them manually

Comment: Sure, a compliant library will _follow_ the redirect, but the app itself needs to 1) know about the redirect, and 2) update its record of the URL.  I think the issue here is properly handling the difference between 301 and 307, not just following the redirect when fetching the URL.

Comment: In my limited testing, it appears that Google Reader is among clients that **do not** update the stored URL for a feed when encountering a 301; so you would need to keep the redirect up permanently.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much every RSS reader - major or minor - will update the feed URL when it encounters a 301 redirect.

Answer (score 1):

In my (limited) experience, most applications will ignore the "permanent" part of a permanent redirect and execute the same logic they would use for a temporary redirect.

Answer (score 0):

It may be necessary to make its site velindekserede about. What to do so to preserve PageRank, link popularity and traffic?

As I understand it, so the solution is called a 301 redirect. It tells search engines that the URL has been permanently moved. How a redirect should be done in a special way. At this link there are different options depending on what kind of server technology you use:

http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php

I just tried it in practice. I use PHP itself on all my sites, so I used the PHP instructions:

I ripped all my old page for tags and content and put the small code snippet on the page. Prisoners of the new URL for the page, and saved it. Tested the page by typing the old URL and then redirects worked. To be absolutely sure that redirects are search engine friendly, I used this "Search Engine Friendly Redirect Checker":

http://www.webconfs.com/redirect-check.php

There no disagreement about how well the 301-redirect is working and whether it can transfer an entire site to a new domain (http://www.webmasterworld.com/link_deve ... 135964.htm), but people's experience says that it is good enough. You just make sure that the new URL has the content as the old page had